# Convert Sum to an Aggregate product expression

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have this expression:

```
group i by i.ItemId into g
select new
{
    Id = g.Key,
    Score = g.Sum(i => i.Score)
}).ToDictionary(o => o.Id, o => o.Score);
```

and instead of `g.Sum` I'd like to get the mathematical product using `Aggregate`.

To make sure it worked the same as `.Sum` (but as product) I tried make an Aggregate function that would just return the sum...

```
Score = g.Aggregate(0.0, (sum, nextItem) => sum + nextItem.Score.Value)
```

However, this does not give the same result as using `.Sum`. Any idas why?

`nextItem.Score` is of type `double?`.

Comment: You keep asking why it doesn't give the same result as Sum, but you have given us no data that demonstrates the problem. *Write a short program that clearly demonstrates the problem that we can compile, run and debug*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static double Product(this IEnumerable<double?> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable
          .Aggregate(1.0, (accumulator, current) => accumulator * current.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: g is of type IGrouping, not IEnumerable so I believe this will not work in my case.

Comment: Yes it will: `public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that in your example you are starting the multiplication with 0.0 - A multiplication with zero yields zero, at the end the result will be zero.

Correct is to use the identity property of multiplication. While adding zero to a number leaves the number of unchanged, the same property holds true for a multiplication with 1. Hence, the correct way to start a product aggregate is to kick off multiplication wit the number 1.0.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that (it was a typo). But just take a look at the sum aggregate for a moment. How come it does not yield the same result as .Sum()?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure about initial value in your aggregate query and you don't acutally need one (like in this example) I would recommend you not to use it at all.

You can use Aggregate overload which doesn't take the initial value - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx

Like this

```
int product = sequence.Aggregate((x, acc) => x * acc);
```

Which evaluates to `item1 * (item2 * (item3 * ... * itemN))`.

instead of

`int product = sequence.Aggregate(1.0, (x, acc) => x * acc);`

Which evaluates to `1.0 * (item1 * (item2 * (item3 * ... * itemN)))`.

//edit:
There is one important difference though. Former one does throw an InvalidOperationException when the input sequence is empty. Latter one returns seed value, therefore 1.0.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But just take a look at the sum aggregate for a moment. How come it does not yield the same result as .Sum()?